# Lightning-Input type=date unable to replicate error

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, lightninginput

We have a lightning-input field, type=date, that has an onchange attribute to do some javascript logic. The logic works about 75% of the time and we can't figure out why. Please assume all things equal and we're correctly binding variables between js, controller and html. I can't give full code for Compliance reasons. I'd like to know if you see anything in the HTML and JS alone that's not a best practice and that would cause inconsistencies. I understand this is very abstract and a bad question, but we're stuck.

lwc HTML:

```html
<lightning-input type="date"
placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" 
date-style="short"
required 
label="String A" 
aria-describedby="String B" 
variant="String C" 
value={recordvariablename.field1__c}
data-fname="field1__c" 
message-when-bad-input="String E" 
onchange={setFVal}>
</lightning-input>
```

lwc js

```js
setFVal(event) {
    this.recordvariablename[event.currentTarget.dataset.fname] = event.currentTarget.value;
    if('field1__c' == event.currentTarget.dataset.fname) { //this is correctly executing each time
        if(('hello' == this.recordvariablename.greeting__c || 'Goodbye' == 
            this.recordvariablename.greeting__c) //this should = true for 100% of the records and the value is set much earlier on the form. I have SOQLd database and all records satisfy this condition.
            &&
           (new Date() - new Date(this.recordvariablename.field1__c)) >= 
           Math.abs(this.label.CalDays*this.label.MiliSec) //this should = true for 100% of the records based on SOQL
           &&
           (new Date(this.recordvariablename.field1__c)>= new 
           Date(this.label.LabelA))){    //this should = true for 100% of the records based on SOQL
                this.ExceptionApply = true;    //only executing 75% of the time.
            } else {
                this.recordvariablename.fieldZ = '';   //this block is executing 25% of the time
                this.ExceptionApply = false;
            }
```

ExceptionApply is used to dynamically render an element like so:

```html
<template if:true={ExceptionApply}>
```

I've compared records, checked FLS, tried different browsers, ensured `ExceptionApply`, `field1__c`, and `fieldZ`, aren't assigned a value anywhere else.

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your own question, and accept it! :)

Comment: Thank you Renato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This is resolved. The issue replicated one day and in Chrome Dev Tools you could see that the Label values were null. We imported them per Salesforce documentation, but found it's a known issue that imported Custom Labels intermittently malfunction: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwVVAA0/custom-labels-imported-in-lwc-are-not-rendered-intermittently-in-communities. We're going to use these suggestions and get Custom Label values through a wire method.